# Eigenvalues of a restriction/interpolation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, interpolation

The restriction operation (maps a $2n$ vector into an $n$ vector) is defined as:

$$R = \frac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix}
 1& 2& 1 \\
 &&1 & 2 &1\\
 && \vdots\\
 &&&& 1& 2& 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

The interpolation operator (maps an n vector into a 2n vector) is:

$$P = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 2 \\
 1 & 1\\
 &2\\
 &1 &1\\
 &&\vdots\\  
 &&&1&1\\
 && &&2\\
 &&&&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

These are rectangular matrices and thus do not have egienvalues, however if you apply them to a matrix, e.g. if $B^{n \times n} = PA^{n/2 \times n/2}R$ the resulting matrix does have eigenvalues. Is it possible to define the eigenvalues of $B$ in terms of those of $A$ for both operators?

Comment: Wouldn't the resulting $B$ matrix be of size $2n\times n$ instead of $n \times n$? Or did you mean to write $B=RAP$ instead of $B=RA$?

Comment: @DanielP I made a typo you are right. I think I fixed it.

Comment: I still think it should be $B=RAP$ not $B=PAR$, since you can't multiply $PA$ together in this order, as $P$ has rows of length $n$ and $A$ has columns of length $2n$.

Comment: @DanielP I messed up my A matrix dimensions. The order is def PAR that I am sure about. You firs restrict, then transform then interpolate.

Comment: Sorry to have so many issues, but $R$ actually isn't a $2n \times n$ matrix if it ends with a $[1\ 2\ 1]$, it has to be a $2n+1 \times n$ matrix, and $P$ is similar. If $R$ is a $2n \times n$ matrix, then it has to end with $[1\ 2]$ in the final row.